# Что создается раньше var или function в javascript?

Tags: javascript

Что создается раньше `var x=0;` или `function y(){};` в javascript?

Comment: Ели память не изменяет, функции всплывают выше и выполняются раньше (все это при условии, что и переменная и функция создаются в одной области видимости)

Comment: это не имеет значения, если Вы различаете "декларацию" и "присвоение"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В процессе разбора кода идентификаторы и `var` и `function` заносятся в `VarScopedDeclaration`.

Далее можно рассмотреть на примере [глобальной области](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation)

Определения начинают обходиться в обратном порядке, выбирая только функции и генераторы (синхронные и асинхронные), причем из дублирующихся имен остается только последние определенные.

Далее добавляются определения для переменных.

Внутри функций, [порядок похож, но несколько отличается](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation)